# What are these slashed noteheads?

Tags: notation

This is taken from a piece of sheet music (which I originally thought was for piano) for "Save Tonight" by Eagle-Eye Cherry.

I do not recognize these notes in the beginning - can somebody tell me what they mean?

[image: "Save Tonight", Intro, mm. 1-2]

Comment: Why so mysterious - what's the piece? More information might help people to answer.

Comment: @replete I'd be careful about making the question specific to a piece. They tend to get closed.

Comment: @endorph, You're missing the point. Your answer couldn't explain the up/down bow symbols, so I'm trying to get a larger excerpt. There are many questions on this site about specific pieces. If the question is asked in a general way, as this one is, there's no problem.

Comment: @replete That's fair, I guess. We're just a little trigger happy on closing questions that are specific to a piece, so I don't want to fly too close to the sun, so to speak.

Comment: @replete - there's enough information contained in the question. The red herring is it's from a piano piece. It's unusual to have a section showing rhythm guitar parts, and strange that bass is included - but without any pitch involved. That'd be my question. And if it's muted, quite possibly, it ought to have x heads instead., as I suspect the question is more about head shape than other signs (V, etc.)

Comment: @Tim, yes, the question is only about noteheads so all these other points are by the by.

Comment: I might have guessed those refer to the "drums" mentioned in the text.  In any case, it sure isn't piano music.    Looks like @endorph has sussed it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This notation (slashed noteheads) is used to show rhythm, without showing specific notes. The player must choose which notes to play, based on the chord symbols.

It's sort of a half-way point between a chord chart, and full notation. I often see it used in a chord chart or lead sheet to notate an important rhythm. They don't use full notation because it's not particularly useful in this context.

The articulations are intended to indicate whether the guitar player should use an [upstroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_bow) [the V-like symbol] or a [downstroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_bow) [the other one, like a square n]. This is because the text underneath indicates that this is a guitar riff (with bass and drums on the second time through). This articulation doesn't really apply to keyboard. You may choose to accent the notes differently, or possibly not play the riff at all (especially if you have a guitarist). You'll have to decide what sounds best.

Comment: To add to this answer: if this was music for singers, it would indicate you speak rather than sing the words.

Comment: @AliceHeaton Isn't speech usually indicated with a cross for the notehead, rather than a diagonal line?